# PHP Strposa single digit matching double and triple digits

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to use `strposa` to stop a part of a loop using `continue` if it finds a match in the array. The problem is if it finds any reference to a digit in the code it just ends, rather than matching the actual input.

I.e. if it finds `6` in `163` it stops. Is there anyway to make it specific.

```
function strposa($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0) {
    if (!is_array($needle)) {
        $needle = array($needle);
    }
    foreach ($needle as $query) {
        if (stripos($haystack, $query, $offset) !== false) {
            return true; // stop on first true result
        }
    }
    return false;
}


$StaffGroups = array (0 => '76', '6', '13', '16', '154', '69');

$ServerGroups = explode(",", $Info['client_servergroups']);

if (strposa($ServerGroups, $StaffGroups, 1)) {
    echo "User is staff";
    Continue;
} else {
    echo "User is not staff";
}
```

The arrays look like this when complete:

```
$StaffGroups( [0] => 76 [1] => 6 [2] => 13 [3] => 16 [4] => 154 [5] => 69 ) 
$ServerGroups ( [0] => 69 [1] => 163 )
```

Would appreciate any help, really stuck at the moment! Apologies if I've answered something that's already been answered but I can't think of a good way to search for this.

Comment: What do you *want* the output to look like?

Comment: I'm not really sure, I just need it to treat a 6 as a 6 rather than flagging the 6 in 163 so that I can finish of this code.

Comment: What is the question/problem now?

Comment: It flags the 6 in 163 rather than treating it as a individual number, I don't want that to happen I want 6 to only flag a 6.

Comment: Why is there a continue after your `echo "User is staff";`? Is this your complete code?

Comment: This is just to tell me that it's found a match and is just for debugging currently, once I fix this issue it'll be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're complicating trying to determine if a given `needle` exists for a given `haystack`. In this case your haystack is the staff groups, and the needle is each element of the server groups. You can get rid of your custom function entirely and use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$StaffGroups = array (0 => '76', '6', '13', '16', '154', '69');
$ServerGroups = explode(",", $Info['client_servergroups']);

foreach ($ServerGroups as $user => $user_id) {
  if (in_array($user_id, $StaffGroups)) {
    echo "User is staff";
  } else {
    echo "User is not staff";
  }
}
```

For each element in `$ServerGroups` you check to see if it exists in `$StaffGroups` and print the appropriate message.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to like the echo "User is staff"; "Syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)"

Comment: That seems to work initially, is there anyway I can make it continue the foreach it's currently running rather than just the one you've created so it stops that foreach and the one it's in.. if that makes sense?

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense? You want to quit after you find a match? Just add `break;` on a line after the `echo`.

Comment: Okay, so that breaks your foreach but it's already in a foreach, is it possible to continue that one? As it needs to skip that client and continue

Comment: Continue what...? The code I posted should replace ALL the code you posted. If there is another foreach in question I'm not aware of it...?

Comment: Yeah, there's a foreach above it like this `foreach($ts3_VirtualServer->clientList() as $Info)
{
  if($Info["client_type"]) continue;
`

Comment: You really should include the entirety of the relevant code in the question itself... it's hard to see in the comments what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Apologies, I've added the foreach that is above it now to explain. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: I've managed to do it using a variable called skip that will have 1 added to it if it's matched.. it's messy but it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Be sure to upvote everyone who helped you out, and accept answers so people help you more in the future!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the exact number then you need to use `==` instead of using stripos. For example:

```
function strposa($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0) {
    if (!is_array($needle)) {
        $needle = array($needle);
    }
    foreach ($needle as $query) {
        if ( $haystack == $query) {
            return true; // stop on first true result
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for common values in two arrays which is what `array_intersect()` is made for:

```
<?php
$StaffGroups = array(76,6,13,16,154,69); 
$ServerGroups = array(69,163);

function userIsStaff($ServerGroups, $StaffGroups) {
  $common = array_intersect($ServerGroups, $StaffGroups);
  return count($common) > 0;
}

if (userIsStaff($ServerGroups, $StaffGroups, 1)) {
    echo "User is staff";
} else {
    echo "User is not staff";
}
```

But I don't understand the meaning of your param `$offset`...